# MVC Have multiple page names off of root of website map to one controller as parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, routes

When I go to the root of my website (MVC) **mysite.com/** I get the nice Home/Index action working. But I want to be able to go to **mysite.com/Home** and mysite.com/about and **mysite.com/contact** and display different content, even though it's still going to Home/Index.cshtml and the page names are being passed as parameters.

If I ever create a new controller names contact and go to **mysite.com/contact** I'm ok with it using the ContactController.

Is this possible and easy to implement?

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult About()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Contact()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

        return View();
    }
}
```

Added controller code, form the default project. But I want to eliminate **About** and **Contact** action results, and handle through **Index** as a parameter.

```
public ActionResult Index(string pageName)
    {

        // do something with parameter, pull data from db and return view

        return View();
    }
```

My ActionResult in controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(string Id)
    {
        if (Id != null)
        {
            // get HTMl from DB
            // build viewModel
            return View(viewModel);
        }
        else
        {
            return View();
        }               
    }
```

If I go to the following URL's I get 
success twice:
[/Website/index/About-Us](http://localhost:9666/Website/index/About-Us) = success

[/?Id=About-Us](http://localhost:9666/?Id=About-Us) = success as query string

[/About-Us](http://localhost:9666/About-Us) = success as expected! wahoo

My route: `routes.MapRoute(
           "Home",
           "{id}",
           new { controller = "Website", action = "Index", area = "", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );`

**But** now all my routes go to the home controller. So my efforts of this tact is not working as hoped.

Comment: How's your controller code looks like ?

Comment: Reviewing the question, I also do not want to have to create a **contact.cshtml** file as I want the default route to handle it as a parameter. Ie: look up in db, and pull content and display as needed.

Comment: It would be good to read into MVC https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381412(v=vs.108).aspx Furthermore this is a question is very low quality.

Comment: I have done about 2-3 hours of reading, and also around 100 google searches. The **reason** for this (trying to make is a quality ask/question is that I am trying to allow the project to act like a website where the pages off of the root can be dynamic, and thus **user generated** based upon  the name the creator gives for the page. It's just part of a larger project but I thought it would be easy to implement.

Comment: If you want `mysite.com/about` to display you `About.cshtml` view, then you need a specific route definition for it (ditto for `mysite.com/contact`). Trying to use the `Index` method to conditionally display different views based on a parameter would be crazy

Comment: I was originally thinking it might be an easy answer, but prob not. A an open source project DNN does it quite elegantly, so that you can create 'pages' on the fly, content in those pages, etc. I was hoping there might be a few lines of code, or a route that at least would get me started, was a bit of need, but if it cant be done without a large amount of code to override the way routes work, then maybe Ill park it for a while.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the Home text from url using the following configuration in RouteConfig.cs... just put the below line of code.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Home",
    "",
    new { action = Index, controller = Home }
);
```

Note : above line of code must place before the

```
 routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Dashboard", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Comment: Thanks @mannan this got me started on the right path and now the answer is above,